# Duration of assignments by status and group

Tags: sql, oracle, remedy

I need to report the duration of how long incidents were in pending/assigned/in progress status for each support group. Data is stored in two tables; ASSIGNMENT_LOG holding history of assignment transfers between support groups, and STATUS_LOG holding history of incident status changes.

Attached is a sample data from one incident. Please have a look and advise how to proceed.

```
WITH slog AS (
select '000000000266702' REQUEST_ID, 'INC000000128540' INCIDENT_NUMBER, 'Assigned' INCIDENTSTATUSTEXT, 1431348757 TIMESTAMPSTART,'11.5.2015 15:52:37' STARTTEXT, 1432033832 TIMESTAMPEND,'19.5.2015 14:10:32' ENDTEXT from dual
union
select '000000000268200','INC000000128540','In Progress',1432033832,'19.5.2015 14:10:32',1432034915,'19.5.2015 14:28:35' from dual
union
select '000000000268205','INC000000128540','Pending',1432034915,'19.5.2015 14:28:35',1432034927,'19.5.2015 14:28:47' from dual
union
select '000000000268206','INC000000128540','Assigned',1432034927,'19.5.2015 14:28:47',1432034970,'19.5.2015 14:29:30' from dual
union 
select '000000000268207','INC000000128540','Pending',1432034970,'19.5.2015 14:29:30',1432034988,'19.5.2015 14:29:48' from dual
union
select '000000000268208','INC000000128540','In Progress',1432034988,'19.5.2015 14:29:48',null,null from dual
), 
alog AS(
select 'INC000000128540' INCIDENT_NUMBER, '000000000103677' REQUEST_ID, 'Helpdesk' ASSIGNED_GROUP, 1431348757 TIMESTAMPSTART, 1431434286 TIMESTAMPEND, '11.5.2015 15:52:37' STARTTEXT,'12.5.2015 15:38:06' ENDTEXT from dual
union
select 'INC000000128540','000000000103816','L1',1431434286,1432033740,'12.5.2015 15:38:06','19.5.2015 14:09:00' from dual
union
select 'INC000000128540','000000000104352','L2',1432033740,1432033777,'19.5.2015 14:09:00','19.5.2015 14:09:37' from dual
union
select 'INC000000128540','000000000104353','L1',1432033777,1432034927,'19.5.2015 14:09:37','19.5.2015 14:28:47' from dual
union
select 'INC000000128540','000000000104354','L2',1432034927,1432034980,'19.5.2015 14:28:47','19.5.2015 14:29:40' from dual
union
select 'INC000000128540','000000000104355','L1',1432034980,null,'19.5.2015 14:29:40',null from dual
)
SELECT 
alog.*, slog.*
from alog, slog
where alog.incident_number = slog.incident_number
order by alog.request_id, slog.request_id
```

Comment: You mean total time in each state across multiple requests; so the combined time of the two pending stages in your example? Perhaps you can add the output you expect for this data? (Not relevant, but why are you storing your date/times as epoch numbers *and* a text string, rather than a single timestamp column?)

Comment: please describe better what you want

Comment: For instance, nothing in the supplied data is called anything like "support group".

Comment: Sorry for not provided detailed information. Alex you are a star! That is exactly what I was looking after.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to identify the overlaps between the timestamp ranges in the two tables. And then having done so, calculate the duration of each overlapping period. This might get you started:

```
select a.incident_number,
  a.assigned_group,
  s.incidentstatustext,
  greatest(s.timestampstart, a.timestampstart) as overlapstart,
  least(nvl(s.timestampend,
      86400*(cast(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) as date) - date '1970-01-01')),
    nvl(a.timestampend,
      86400*(cast(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) as date) - date '1970-01-01')))
    as overlapend,
  least(nvl(s.timestampend,
      86400*(cast(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) as date) - date '1970-01-01')),
    nvl(a.timestampend,
      86400*(cast(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) as date) - date '1970-01-01')))
    - greatest(s.timestampstart, a.timestampstart) as duration,
  -- just to see where values are coming from
  a.timestampstart as a_start,
  a.timestampend as a_end,
  s.timestampstart as s_start,
  s.timestampend as s_end
from alog a
join slog s on s.incident_number = a.incident_number
and (a.timestampend is null or s.timestampstart <= a.timestampend)
and (s.timestampend is null or s.timestampend >= a.timestampstart)
order by incident_number, overlapstart;
```

Which with your sample data gets:

```
INCIDENT_NUMBER ASSIGNED INCIDENTSTA   OVERLAPSTART     OVERLAPEND       DURATION        A_START          A_END        S_START          S_END
--------------- -------- ----------- -------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- --------------
INC000000128540 Helpdesk Assigned        1431348757     1431434286          85529     1431348757     1431434286     1431348757     1432033832
INC000000128540 L1       Assigned        1431434286     1432033740         599454     1431434286     1432033740     1431348757     1432033832
INC000000128540 L2       Assigned        1432033740     1432033777             37     1432033740     1432033777     1431348757     1432033832
INC000000128540 L1       Assigned        1432033777     1432033832             55     1432033777     1432034927     1431348757     1432033832
INC000000128540 L1       In Progress     1432033832     1432034915           1083     1432033777     1432034927     1432033832     1432034915
INC000000128540 L1       Pending         1432034915     1432034927             12     1432033777     1432034927     1432034915     1432034927
INC000000128540 L2       Pending         1432034927     1432034927              0     1432034927     1432034980     1432034915     1432034927
INC000000128540 L1       Assigned        1432034927     1432034927              0     1432033777     1432034927     1432034927     1432034970
INC000000128540 L2       Assigned        1432034927     1432034970             43     1432034927     1432034980     1432034927     1432034970
INC000000128540 L2       Pending         1432034970     1432034980             10     1432034927     1432034980     1432034970     1432034988
INC000000128540 L1       Pending         1432034980     1432034988              8     1432034980                    1432034970     1432034988
INC000000128540 L1       In Progress     1432034988     1432205373         170385     1432034980                    1432034988
```

I've assumed you want to see each overlapping time separately, rather than summed by assigned group and status. I've also worked form the (hopefully UTC) epoch dates rather than the text versions to simplify the time zone adjustment - which is needed to give a nominal end date for the open-ended records.

Where the status and assigned group changed at exactly the same time you get more combinations than you really want, with the redundant ones having zero duration, so you can eliminate those. That's easier to do with a subquery, which simplifies the whole thing a bit anyway:

```
select incident_number,
  assigned_group,
  incidentstatustext,
  overlapstart,
  overlapend,
  overlapend - overlapstart as duration
from (
  select a.incident_number,
    a.assigned_group,
    s.incidentstatustext,
    greatest(s.timestampstart, a.timestampstart) as overlapstart,
    least(nvl(s.timestampend,
        86400*(cast(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) as date) - date '1970-01-01')),
      nvl(a.timestampend,
        86400*(cast(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) as date) - date '1970-01-01')))
        as overlapend
  from alog a
  join slog s on s.incident_number = a.incident_number
  and (a.timestampend is null or s.timestampstart <= a.timestampend)
  and (s.timestampend is null or s.timestampend >= a.timestampstart)
)
where overlapend != overlapstart -- get rid of zeros
order by incident_number, overlapstart;
```

Which gets the same result for the non-zero durations:

```
INCIDENT_NUMBER ASSIGNED INCIDENTSTA   OVERLAPSTART     OVERLAPEND       DURATION
--------------- -------- ----------- -------------- -------------- --------------
INC000000128540 Helpdesk Assigned        1431348757     1431434286          85529
INC000000128540 L1       Assigned        1431434286     1432033740         599454
INC000000128540 L2       Assigned        1432033740     1432033777             37
INC000000128540 L1       Assigned        1432033777     1432033832             55
INC000000128540 L1       In Progress     1432033832     1432034915           1083
INC000000128540 L1       Pending         1432034915     1432034927             12
INC000000128540 L2       Assigned        1432034927     1432034970             43
INC000000128540 L2       Pending         1432034970     1432034980             10
INC000000128540 L1       Pending         1432034980     1432034988              8
INC000000128540 L1       In Progress     1432034988     1432205374         170386
```

The durations are in seconds, and you can convert that to whatever format you want to report in.